# I need an operator like withLatestFrom, except it fires as soon as both Observables have emitted a value

Tags: angular, rxjs

So withLatestFrom is very close to what I need, but it has a weird behavior. It only emits a value if the "master" emits AFTER the "slave".
As shown in this Marble diagram:

```
--1----2-------2---- (source)
----a-------b------- (other1)
-------2a------2b--
```

I need an operator which behaves like this:

```
--1------2-------2---- (source)
----a---------b------- (other1)
----1a---2a------2b--
```

and this:

```
------1------2-------2---- (source)
--a--------------b------- (other1)
------1a-----2a------2b--
```

In other words, it basically needs to act like CombineLatest for the first emits, and then behave like withLatestFrom afterwards.
How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: I don't get it, where is the difference between combineLatest and what you need? I'd say combineLatest is exactly what you need. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm It's not. CombineLatest emits a value every time either of the observables emits a value. I want it to emit only when the "source" emits, but it must also wait until both observables have emitted at least one value.

Comment: I got it now, thank you. I will think about a solution

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an operator specific to that but try the snippet below.

Try this:

```
combineLatest(
  source,
  other1.pipe(
    take(1), // only take one emission, the take(1) might kill this observable and stop further emissions but give it a try
  )
).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(other1),
).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  const source = result[0][0]; // I am not sure how to destructure it but I suspect
  const other1 = result[1]; // result will be a 2d array in the form of
                               // [[source, firstEmissionOther1], other1]
  console.log(source); 
  console.log(other1);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the pairwise operator

```
combineLatest([master$, slave$])
  .pipe(
    startWith([null, null]),
    pairwise(),
    filter(([prev, curr]) => curr[0] !== prev[0]),
    map(([prev, curr]) => curr)
  )
  .subscribe(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
```

See the same on stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4uyclu?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

#### `combineLatest` with a distinct source stream.

One approach might be to use `combineLatest` and ignore emissions that don't origionate from the source. The typical caveats of JS object comparison do apply here so you may want to adjust your custom comparer function accordingly.

```
combineLatest(
  source$,
  latestFrom$
).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev[0] === curr[0])
)
```